# Non-linear optimization with Tensorflow-probability

Tags: python, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to implement a Gaussian fitting using TensorFlow-probability's Nelder-Mead optimizer: `tfp.optimizer.nelder_mead_minimize()`. It does not converge, while `scipy.optimizer.minimize()` provide good result in less than 1 second of computation time. I am probably doing something wrong but i can't figure what ? Can someone help me on this ?

I am using :

```
python                    3.7.3
tensorflow-probability    0.8
tensorflow                2.0
```

Here's my code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

# Define the gaussian model : y = 1/(sigma * sqrt(2 pi)) * exp(- (x-mu)²/(2*sigma²))
pi = np.pi
def model(x, theta):
    y = 1/(theta[1]*tf.sqrt(2*pi)) * tf.exp(-(x-theta[0])**2 /(2*theta[1]**2))
    return y


# Define the loss (least mean square)
def loss_function(theta, y, x, callback=False, n_iterations=1):
    global n_epochs_cb
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, model(x, theta))
    if callback:
        if n_epochs_cb % (n_iterations/10.) == 0:
            print('{0:4d}   {1:}   {2: 3.6f}'.format(n_epochs_cb, theta, loss))
    n_epochs_cb = n_epochs_cb + 1
    return loss


# Generate some data
theta_true = [3, 2]
X = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.5) 
Y = model(X, theta_true) 
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = [20, 10])
# ax.scatter(X, Y, label='data', alpha=0.5)

# initialize parameters 
theta = tf.constant(tf.random.uniform([2], 0, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name='theta')
n_iterations = 100
n_epochs_cb = 1

# minimization
print('{0:4s}   {1:9s}               {2:9s}'.format('Iter', 'theta', 'loss'))
optim_results = tfp.optimizer.nelder_mead_minimize(lambda theta: loss_function(theta, X, Y, True, n_iterations),
                                                   initial_vertex=theta,
                                                   func_tolerance=1e-8,
                                                   position_tolerance=1e-8,
                                                   max_iterations=n_iterations)   

print("theta_true", theta_true)
print("theta_est", optim_results.position.numpy())
print("convergenced:", optim_results.converged.numpy())
print("number of function evaluation", optim_results.num_objective_evaluations.numpy())
print("number of iterations", optim_results.num_iterations.numpy())
print("objective value", optim_results.objective_value.numpy())
```

Optimization stop around 50 iterations and return :

```
Iter   theta                   loss     
  10   [0.1448533 6.7525005]    33.408031
  20   [-0.2385819 28.76061  ]    33.382130
  30   [ -4.1879644 260.84622  ]    33.375771
  40   [ -34.722183 2053.5083  ]    33.375099
  50   [ -418.6432 24589.836 ]    33.375008
theta_true [3, 2]
theta_est [ -488.44122 28687.352  ]
convergenced: True
number of function evaluation 55
number of iterations 35
objective value 33.375008
```

I run the same problem using `minimize()` from `scipy.optimize` with `'Nelder-Mead'` method and it gives :

```
Iter   theta                                          loss     
  10   [4.61612335 4.40795762]    0.007583
  20   [3.19502416 2.09290338]    0.001023
  30   [3.01845636 1.99504269]    0.000091
  40   [2.99843397 2.00065615]    0.000010
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000010
         Iterations: 44
         Function evaluations: 96
computation time 0.046 seconds
```

I would expect to have the same performance using tensorflow-probability's Nelder-Mead optimizer and Scipy.optimize's Nelder-mead optimizer.

What am I doing wrong ?

**Edit :** 
Found the mistake in the definition of the loss function. the following code is now converging :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

# Define the gaussian model : y = 1/(sigma * sqrt(2 pi)) * exp(- (x-mu)²/(2*sigma²))
pi = np.pi
def model(x, theta):
    y =  1/(theta[1]*tf.sqrt(2*pi)) * tf.exp(-(x-theta[0])**2 /(2*theta[1]**2))
    return y


# Define the loss (least mean square)
def loss_function(theta, y, x, callback=False, n_iterations=1):
    global n_epochs_cb
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, model(x, theta))
    if callback:
        if n_epochs_cb % (n_iterations/10.) == 0:
            print('{0:4d}   {1:}   {2: 3.6f}'.format(n_epochs_cb, theta, loss))
    n_epochs_cb = n_epochs_cb + 1
    return loss

# Generate some data
theta_true = [3, 2]
X = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.5, dtype=np.float32) 
Y = model(X, theta_true) 
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = [20, 10])
# ax.scatter(X, Y, label='data', alpha=0.5)

# initialize parameters 
theta = tf.constant(tf.random.uniform([2], 0, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name='theta')

print("theta_true", theta_true)
print("theta_init", theta.numpy())

n_iterations = 100
n_epochs_cb = 1

# minimization
print('{0:4s}   {1:9s}               {2:9s}'.format('Iter', 'theta', 'loss'))
optim_results = tfp.optimizer.nelder_mead_minimize(lambda theta: loss_function(theta, Y, X, True, n_iterations),
                                                   initial_vertex=theta,
                                                   func_tolerance=1e-8,
                                                   position_tolerance=1e-8,
                                                   max_iterations=n_iterations)   


print("theta_est", optim_results.position.numpy())
print("convergenced:", optim_results.converged.numpy())
print("number of function evaluation", optim_results.num_objective_evaluations.numpy())
print("number of iterations", optim_results.num_iterations.numpy())
print("objective value", optim_results.objective_value.numpy())
```

Comment: do you start with the same initial parameters in both cases? try to start with the true parameters in order to exclude any errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do start with the same initial parameters in both cases. I also tried starting with the true parameters: `scipy.optimizer.minimize()` stops after 10 iterations on the good estimations while `tfp.optimizer.nelder_mead_minimize()` diverges as well as with random initialization

Comment: if tensorflow diverges even from the true parameters then most probably your implementation of the loss function is wrong. you would have to debug it one way or the other. maybe display the outputs of the loss function on a 2D grid around the true parameters (it's only two parameters anyway) and verify that there is a minimum at the right place.

Comment: Yes you are right, I found the error and posted the good implementation. Thanks !